# use dll in qt creator

Tags: qt4

how can use dll in qt Creator? which i created in visual Studio.

Comment: Just like you use dlls in other C++ code?

Answer (score 0):

DLLs define an interface, so probably yes, but that is more a compiler question (microsofts compiler vs mingw32) than an IDE question.